# Pasar Array a Int - PHP

Tags: php, pdo

necesito obtener el id del alumno con su rut(n° de identificacion) lo cual logro en la query que realizo en PDO el problema en que me regresa un array y no un int.

Entonces estaba en la duda transformo el valor obtenido en un integer o cambio la query para obtener un integer, segun yo tengo entendido siempre me regresa un array.

Y como lo puedo realizar.

Querry

```
public function alumnos_id($rut){

    try {
        $result = array();
        $sql = "SELECT alu_id FROM alumno WHERE alu_rut='$rut'";
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);        
        $stm->execute();

       foreach ($stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $r) {

            $alm = array(
                            'alu_id' => $r->alu_id
                        );
            $result[] = $alm;
        }   

        return $result;    

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e;
        }

}
```

PHP

```
require_once('funciones/web_services/alumnos_ws.php');
$alumnos_obj = new alumnos_ws();
$alumnos_id = $alumnos_obj->alumnos_id($rut_alumno);

echo $alumnos_id;
```

Esto me devuelve en pantalla una palabra "Array".

Comment: Si necesitas un `int`, obtén un `int`. PDO tiene métodos para todo. Por ejemplo, existe el método [`fetchColumn`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) el cual te obtiene una columna en específico. A no ser que necesites varias columnas, entoces sí podrías obtener un array y leerlo. Señalo también que estás desperdiciando PDO, las consultas no se preparan así, debes separar el valor de `$rut` de la instrucción SQL, protegiendo tu consulta de la Inyección SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si sólo necesitas el id del alumno, puedes usar **[`fetchColumn()`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)** como he comentado antes. Es el método adecuado cuando **sólo necesitamos una columna**. Todo lo que haces en el `foreach` sobra en este caso, por eso lo he comentado.

He modificado el código dándole seguridad, por ello se crea una consulta preparada:

```
    $sql = "SELECT alu_id FROM alumno WHERE alu_rut =: rut";
```

Y luego se pasa el valor aparte:

```
    $stm->bindValue(":rut",$rut);
```

De ese modo evitamos la Inyección SQL.

La función quedaría así:

```
public function alumnos_id($rut){

    try {
        /* $result no sería un array
        $result = array();
        */ 
        $sql = "SELECT alu_id FROM alumno WHERE alu_rut =: rut";
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);        
        $stm->bindValue(":rut",$rut);
        $stm->execute();
        $result = $stm->fetchColumn();

       /* Si esperas un solo resultado esto sobra ...

       foreach ($stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $r) {

            $alm = array(
                            'alu_id' => $r->alu_id
                        );
            $result[] = $alm;
        }   

        */     
        return $result;    

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e;
        }

}
```